# cell click not working when grid view contains data from two tables

Tags: c#

I have shown data in same grid view from two different tables.
When I click the buttons in the UI the result is shown in the grid view accordingly.
Now I want to click on a cell in the grid view and pass the ID of the respective row to another text box (in this case "M_ID").

It works, but when adding the next line to pass the "A_ID" which is from another table it doesn't work.

there are two buttons in the UI and both buttons returns respective results from two different tables (not at a time but when I press them) in the same grid view when i press them.

```
private void datagridviewResult_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = this.datagridviewResult.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            txtGenerateId.Text = row.Cells["M_ID"].Value.ToString();
            txtGenerateId.Text = row.Cells["A_ID"].Value.ToString();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you define exactly what you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get an exception? Is the data from the first table overwritten by the data from the second?

Comment: Are you meaning to overwrite `txtGenerateId.Text` with `A_ID` immediately after `M_ID`?

Comment: yes i want to overwrite txtGenerateId.Text with A_ID immediately after M_ID  @CodeMaverick

Comment: @Ishrak - That makes ***zero*** sense. Why not remove the `M_ID` line just leaving you with the `A_ID` line that you want? Or are you saying that you want to ***append*** `A_ID` to `M_ID`?

Comment: actually it's my fault that i wasn't able to clarify my problem basically it's the type of problem which you want to show someone not to write a long boring description about it ..... sorry @CodeMaverick

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are expecting the output to be but maybe you don't want to overwrite `txtGenerateId.Text`, something like this:

```
private void datagridviewResult_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = this.datagridviewResult.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            txtGenerateId.Text = string.Format("{0},{1}", 
                row.Cells["M_ID"].Value.ToString(),
                row.Cells["A_ID"].Value.ToString()); 

        }
    }
```

This will place the results from both tables in the text box separated by a comma. The `{0},{1}` is a template and you can switch the comma for however you want to display both results.